# Table Rows wrapped in a Form are read as all even or all odd in css. Any idea why?

Tags: css, forms, css-selectors, css-tables

Here is an odd one.  I have table rows wrapped in a form to make the row clickable and send back data through post to the parent page.  Here is a sample of my html, which is generated in a php function with data from a mysql database:

```css
    table.iframetbl {
     width: 90%;
     margin-left: auto;
     margin-right: auto;
     text-align: center;
     vertical-align: middle;
     border: 2px solid #000000;
     border-collapse:collapse;
     font-family: "Lucida Grande", "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Sans", "DejaVu Sans", Verdana, sans-serif;
     font-size: 8pt;
    }
    table.iframetbl th {
     background-color: #538073;
     color: #F0F0F0;
    }
    table.iframetbl td {
     white-space:break-word;
     max-width:230px;
     font-size:8pt;
    }
    table.iframetbl tr:nth-child(odd) {
     background-color: #FFFFFF;
    }
    table.iframetbl tr:nth-child(even) {
     background-color: #E5E5E5;
    }
    table.iframetbl tr.reg {
     background-color: #F9F180;
    }
```

```html
<table class="iframetbl" >
      <tr>
        <th>Order #</th>
        <th>Customer#</th>
        <th>Entry Date</th>
      </tr>
      <form id="15002588-000" action="/2m/Reports/orderlines.php" target="_parent" method="post">
     <input type="hidden" name="whse" value="15" />
     <input type="hidden" name="ordernum" value="15002588-000" />
     <tr onClick="document.getElementById('15002588-000').submit()">
      <td>15002588-000</td>
      <td>150004</td>
      <td>2016-09-28</td>
     </tr></form>
      <form id="15002587-000" action="/2m/Reports/orderlines.php" target="_parent" method="post">
     <input type="hidden" name="whse" value="15" />
     <input type="hidden" name="ordernum" value="15002587-000" />
     <tr onClick="document.getElementById('15002587-000').submit()">
      <td>15002587-000</td>
      <td>150058</td>
      <td>2016-09-28</td>
     </tr></form>
      <form id="15002585-000" action="/2m/Reports/orderlines.php" target="_parent" method="post">
     <input type="hidden" name="whse" value="15" />
     <input type="hidden" name="ordernum" value="15002585-000" />
     <tr onClick="document.getElementById('15002585-000').submit()">
      <td>15002585-000</td>
      <td>150044</td>
      <td>2016-09-28</td>
     </tr></form>
      <form id="15002584-000" action="/2m/Reports/orderlines.php" target="_parent" method="post">
     <input type="hidden" name="whse" value="15" />
     <input type="hidden" name="ordernum" value="15002584-000" />
     <tr onClick="document.getElementById('15002584-000').submit()">
      <td>15002584-000</td>
      <td>150019</td>
      <td>2016-09-28</td>
     </tr></form>
      <form id="15002583-000" action="/2m/Reports/orderlines.php" target="_parent" method="post">
     <input type="hidden" name="whse" value="15" />
     <input type="hidden" name="ordernum" value="15002583-000" />
     <tr onClick="document.getElementById('15002583-000').submit()">
      <td>15002583-000</td>
      <td>150030</td>
      <td>2016-09-28</td>
     </tr></form>
      </table>
```

Everything works as far as functionality - I can click on my rows and it sends the data back to the parent page this table is generated from, etc.  The problem is the css that changes the odd and even row background colors isn't working right.  When I inspect the element, it shows each row as even (or odd depending on browser - IE and Chrome show them all as odd and in jsfiddle they are all even).  If I remove the form from around the rows, the css reads the proper nth-child and the colors work.  I've never run into this before, does anyone have a solution?

Here is the code in a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kj02008w/)

Comment: Have you tried putting the form inside the table row instead? The way you are doing it seems a little weird and backwards.

Comment: Or instead of `table.iframetbl tr:nth-child(odd)` try `table.iframebtl > form:nth-child(odd) > tr`. Do the same for the even.

Comment: Putting the form inside the table row fixed the issue.  I'm not sure why I had the form wrapped around the row tbh, I recycled the code from another page I wrote a while back.  Thanks!!

Comment: Glad that solved it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For future visitors, the issue was wrapping the `tr` elements in a `form`. The `form` needs to be inside the `tr` instead.